# Bind ListView to ArrayList and Display

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, listview, data-binding

I don't usually work with these types of controls, so I could be completely on the wrong track here..

The end goal is to have a dataset of records with ProductTitle, ProductURL and ProductDescription.  Then have those records displayed in a 3 column format, with additional rows if needed.  For example:

records 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ,6 and 7 should show

```
1 - 2 - 3

4 - 5 - 6

7
```

---

The error I'm getting is

> System.Web.HttpException: DataBinding:
>   'System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListItem' does not contain a property with
>   the name 'ProductTitle'.

The Front-End side:

```
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server" GroupItemCount="3" OnLoad="ListView1_Load">

        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table border="0" cellpadding="5">
                            <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="groupPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>

        <GroupTemplate>
            <tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server" ID="itemPlaceHolder"></asp:PlaceHolder>
            </tr>
        </GroupTemplate>

        <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
                <div>
                    <div><%#Eval("ProductTitle")%></div>
                    <img alt="Test Image" src="<%#Eval("ProductURL")%>" />
                    <div><%# Eval("ProductDescription")%></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>  
</div>
```

I've got my Code-Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

End Sub


Protected Sub ListView1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myPaaams As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    myPaaams.Add(New ListItem("ProductTitle", "Adams Test"))
    myPaaams.Add(New ListItem("ProductURL", "Adams Test"))
    myPaaams.Add(New ListItem("ProductDescription", "Adams Test"))

    ListView1.DataSource = myPaaams
    ListView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

---

**I've also tried** the following code for my ListView Load event, but this fails with the same error.

```
Protected Sub ListView1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myParams As ArrayList = New ArrayList

    Dim variable As New Dictionary(Of String, String) From {{"ProductTitle", "Adams Test"}, _
                                                            {"ProductURL", "value2"}, _
                                                            {"ProductDescription", "value2"}}

    myParams.Add(variable)

    ListView1.DataSource = myParams
    ListView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a class, such as

```
Public Class Products
    Public Property ProductTitle As String
    Public Property ProductURL as String
    Public Property ProductDescription as String
End Class


Protected Sub ListView1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    Dim myParams As BindingList(of Products)= New BindingList(of Products)

    Dim p as Products = New Products With {.ProductTitle = "Title", 
                                         .ProductURL = "URL",
                                         .ProductDescription="Description"}

    myParams.Add(p)
    ListView1.DataSource = myParams
    ListView1.DataBind()
End Sub
```

The reason why what you are trying isn't working, is because you are trying to manually create a new list item, and then bind against it -- that won't work, as the list item doesn't have the right properties.

Comment: Just tried this, but I still get the same error message.  The error occurs on ListView1.DataBind()

Comment: I fixed the typos in my code, copied your aspx code into a new project (editted to change img to div) and pasted my code into the codebehind--works (after adding import for bindinglist).

Comment: Does it make a difference that this is an ASCX and not an ASPX? We work in DNN and all code is done in separate modules / controls, instead of full pages.

Comment: Nevermind, I copied your revised code in and it works just fine.  I thought I had fixed the typos myself but apparently not.  Thank you for the help!!!

Comment: You're welcome.  I'd add that ArrayList is a relic of .Net 1.0, and I wouldn't recommend using it for anything new. It may not make much of a difference in this particular scenario (using eval on the otherside), but still...Apologizes for the typos, iPads are great, but do have some limitations.